# What does the hash(#) operator do in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, operators, dbvisualizer

I'm trying to replicate a function that a former employee built within Postgres in another language and having trouble working out what the # operator does.  I've run a few numbers through it and there doesn't seem to be any consistency in the results:

```
select  1 # 1  --0
        ,1 # 2 --3
        ,1 # 3 --2
        ,1 # 4 --5
        ,1 # 5 --4
        ,2 # 2 --0
        ,2 # 3 --1
        ,2 # 4 --6
```

If anyone is able to explain I would be hugely grateful!

Comment: Looks like "bit xor".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially it's called "bitwise XOR". See [9.6. Bit String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-bitstring.html).

It computes a XOR operation between each bit of the two counterparts.

For example:

```
select 10 # 12
```

Would be computed as a XOR between their corresponding binary digits:

```
1 0 1 0 (decimal 10)
1 1 0 0 (decimal 12)
-------
0 1 1 0 (decimal 6)
```

Result:

```
6
```

Comment: Legend, thanks - this is just the answer I was looking for!